# R Histogram and Boxplot alignment

Tags: r, layout, histogram, bar-chart, par

I have the problem that i want to put barplot under a histogram where the barplot of a value is exactly under the certain value of the histogram. Unfortunately the scaling of the histogram is not the same as in the barplot and additionally there is a little gap in the histogram.

Is there a possibility to rearrange that?

```
# data
set.seed(4566)
a <- rnorm(100)
a <- dnorm(a)*10+1 
data <- a

#data plot 2
values <- matrix(,,3)
values[1,1] <- 1
values[1,2] <- 2
values[1,3] <- 3
colnames(values) <- c('Mean','Best 50%','Worst 50%')

# layout boxplot is at the bottom 
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE), height = c(3,1))
par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1),oma=c(0,2,1,1))
b <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
hist(data,xlim = range(0:6),ylim=range(0:25),col = "blue",breaks=b)
barplot(values, horiz=T, xlim=range(0:6),ylim=range(0:3),las=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `xaxs` parameter within the `hist` call

```
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE), height = c(3,1))
par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1),oma=c(0,2,1,1))
hist(data,xlim = range(0:6),ylim=range(0:25),col = "blue", breaks=b, xaxs="i")
barplot(values, horiz=T, xlim=range(0:6),ylim=range(0:3), las=1)
```

which gives

[image]

The `xaxs` parameter is used for the calculation of the x-axis (see `?par`).

Have a look at what it does

The default `xaxs = "r"`

```
hist(data,xlim = range(0:6),ylim=range(0:25),col = "blue", breaks=b, xaxs="r")
par("usr")
#[1] -0.24  6.24 -1.00 26.00
```

The first two points give the x axis limits - you can see it has been expanded.
To force this to stay within the range of the data you can use the `xaxs="i"` option

```
hist(data,xlim = range(0:6),ylim=range(0:25),col = "blue", breaks=b, xaxs="i")
par("usr")
#[1]  0  6 -1 26
```

Which agrees with your barplot

```
barplot(values, horiz=T, xlim=range(0:6),ylim=range(0:3), las=1)
par("usr")
#[1]  0.00  6.00 -0.12  3.12
```